# Problems with Drupal 7's clean URLs

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, clean-urls, pathauto

I've looked around and I couldn't find an answer to my question so here it is.

Clean URLs are enabled on my Drupal 7 website and are "working" in the sense that I can access the About Us page with www.mysite.com/about-us and with www.mysite.com/node/12.

However, usually with Wordpress and the get_permalink() function, every menu/links like ?p=12 get redirected/rewritten to /about-us.  But with Drupal, my menu links are in the form node/12 , and when I click on a link I get the page /node/12, not /about-us.

Any idea how I can get the rewriting/re-routing done automatically?

Thanks!

Comment: Drupal should attempt to use a path alias whenever it is available, so this might be a configuration problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet would be the [Global redirect](http://drupal.org/project/globalredirect) module. The first of its many functions is:

> Checks the current URL for an alias and does a 301 redirect to it if it is not being used.

I've used it in just about every Drupal site I've ever made and it works well.

Comment: I like that.  Let me download this module! :o)

Comment: That's pretty much what I wanted to accomplish ... thank you very much!

Comment: If you want to get the aliased and ready-to-go URL of the page, use url('node/12'). This will change the link itself rather than a redirect at destination. 
Global Redirect is always a must-have module anyway.